# jquery add or remove class using toggleClass() within on click method

Tags: jquery

Hi i created accordion function using jquery by `toggleClass` function.

my [fiddle for this case](http://jsfiddle.net/Vivekranth/dE9sJ/9/)

here while clicking `accordion` class a `active` class will added to the same class i added some styles to `active` class for displaying child classes.Now the problem is the accordion toggled if we click anywhere of `accordion` class or its child classes whats wrong on it?
my JS

```
$('.accordion').on('click', function() {
            $(this).toggleClass('active'); 
        });
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with it, that's how jQuery (and Javascript) works. If you don't want it to happen on `.accordion`, be more specific with your selector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.accordion > a.title').on('click', function() {
  $(this).parent().toggleClass('active'); 
});
```

As RGraham says, there was nothing wrong with it, it was doing exactly what you told it to. If you want it to toggle only when you click on the title, then you need to catch the events on the title, not the whole accordion div.

Answer (score 1):

you have to use `.parent()` of `Jquery` function.

```
$('.title').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('active'); 
});
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dE9sJ/11/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   $('.accordion > a.title').on('click', function() {
       $(this).parent().toggleClass('active'); 
   });
```

or

```
   $('a.title').on('click', function() {
       $(this).parent().toggleClass('active'); 
   });
```

here is updated [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dE9sJ/12/)